# Why does baking bevel node to normal texture create sharp edges?

Tags: texture-baking, bevel, normal-map

[image: modling]

[image]

Here is my model.

[image]

This is the bevel node preview.

[image]

This is the result after baking, I don't understand why it breaks it piece by piece.

**I am not marking the sharp edges manually.**

[image]

I tried to change the render parameters and changing CUDA to OptiX, but it won't help. Triangulate doesn't work either.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I aready slove the problem,it's a bug or compatible problem.

***short version : i creat this scens with 3.3.6,then i used 3.5.1 open this scens and bake it,the compatibility cause this issue,export fbx to 3.5.1 wouldn't have this problem.***

i creat this scens with 3.3.6,and 3.3.6 have a bake issues,when bake bevel node to normal texture,it will have some spots in normal map.
[image]

but at new version 3.5.0,it bake clean and nice normal maps,it seems blender have improve the bake funtion in new version.

[image]

*****but i made a mistake*****

i open this 3.3.6 scens direct with 3.5.0,because blender higher version able to open lower version scens ,i do that a lot and it doesn't have problems before,so i thought this time will be ok.

[image]

here is the problem when i open 3.3.6 scens with 3.5.0,it have a huge issue with shade smooth,so i inferred that 3.5.0 have change the modle algorithm cause the smooth issue.

***then i made second mistake.***

i think that should be some bug,so i download 3.5.1,and it's ok in 3.5.1.

[image]

but with 3.5.0 issue,we know in some place 3.5 version had change ,though 3.5.1 can't see it,it's still exist.

then we knew,the bake was terrible and no idea how to fix.

[image]

so i think blender's compatibility is good,but when you have to change the version of blender,better export fbx to the newer version.